# FB login callback function not responding if user is already logged in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

I am using fb connect  using js. This is my code:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true
      });

      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        obj=response.authResponse;
        token=obj.accessToken;
        setCookie("access_token_fb", token, '2');

        window.location.reload();
      },true);
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
```

for login I am using:

```
 <div class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_checkins"  >Login with Facebook</div>
```

'auth.login' in subscribe function has a response handler it is only being called when user click on fb button and not already logged into FB, enter his/her email address and password in fb window . While if a user is already logged in facebook then fb dialog open and close. It doesnot then pass control to response hander. I read somewhere that force="true" enable it to detect status change and call call back function. But I don't know where to add force ture. I think it should be in login div. Is it true or is there some other approach?

thanks for you time.

Comment: I am having same problem. I noticed that if it is app linked user then it shows this behavior. Please help.

Comment: I want to call event (same as event after login) after clicking on login button if all ready logged in app user.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Because you seem to be using fb login plugin, if the user is logged in and already connected to your app, the login button [will not be shown](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) (read the Note there).

You can subscribe to `auth.statusChange` event with a custom button if you still want to do that. Explained it in my answer.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. And despite what the documentation says, that login button always shows on my site, even if the user's already logged in. I don't have a problem with the button always showing up. But if a user is logs out of my site then wants to log back in again using the FB login button, they can't because the button doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: @EastofNowhere ask another question with your code that you are using, and then place that question's link here so that we can see your code and tell you better

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Though I believe that DMCS has given a correct solution to the problem, here is another way to approach. Use FB.login method with a custom login link.

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'YOUR-APP-ID',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });
};

function facebookLogin() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Authenticated!');
            // location.reload(); //or do whatever you want
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    },
    {
        scope: 'email,user_checkins'
    });
}

(function(d) {
    var js,
    id = 'facebook-jssdk';
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
} (document));
</script>
```

Body markup:

```
<div id='fb-root></div><!-- required for SDK initialization -->
<a id='fb-login' href='#' onclick='facebookLogin()'>Login with Facebook</a>
```

When you click on the button, it will run the callback function inside FB.login.

**Method 2:**

Alternatively, using FB login button plugin, you can subscribe to `auth.statusChange` and check for the status of the user in response.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
  // check for status in the response
});
```

Note if you are using fb login button plugin, and the user is already logged in and connected to the app, no login button is shown (read it in the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/))

Comment: Your 1st method solved my problem. I called function facebookLogin() on clicking custom login button. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest letting Facebook do the heavy lifting for you. 
Please note some changes: 1. channelUrl specified, 2. use of FB.getLoginStatus 3. removal of setting a cookie. 4. change of event to listen to (so in case they log out in a different window, or deauth your app elsewhere, etc )

```
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
            channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html' // Channel File
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {

                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                // Do something with the access token


            } else {
                // Subscribe to the event 'auth.authResponseChange' and wait for the user to autenticate
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
                    // nothing more needed than to reload the page
                    window.location.reload();
                },true);      

                // now dynamically show the login plugin
                $('#mydiv').show();      
            }
        });


        };
        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));
  </script>
```

Comment: This will call after loading page. I want to call after clicking login button.

Comment: It will call on clicking login button.  See the FB.Event.Subscribe method.  Again, this way is to let the framework do the heavy lifting and it also follows under your requirement of "*'auth.login' in subscribe function has a response handler it is only being called when user click on fb button and not already logged into FB*"

Answer (score 2):

When you intialize the FB SDK with `status:true` it will fetch the login status from the user and store it. From that point on when you make calls to `FB.getLoginStatus()` it isnt accessing fetching the latest data from FB but is instead referring to the locally stored variables that were set at the point of `FB.init()` - I think its only refreshed once every 20 mins (see https://github.com/facebook/facebook-js-sdk/commit/5b15174c7c9b9ea669499804d4a4c7d80771b036) - however you can force the refresh by doing this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function() {...}, /*FORCE*/ true);
```

This should then fire your `auth.login` event or you could just pass the handler you defined for that event to `FB.getLoginStatus` as well.

Can even go a set further and poll this function like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function() {...}, /*FORCE*/ true);
}, 10000); // poll every 10 seconds
```

Comment: I am getting login status well. While if a user is already logged in facebook then fb dialog open and close. It doesn't then pass control to response hander after clicking on login button.

Answer (score 1):

Change from "status : true," to "status : false," and I believe it'll do what you want. The problem is status : true makes the status check happen on init, so there is nothing to change when the user clicks the button.

Found the answer on next-to-last comment here: http://www.bubblefoundry.com/blog/2011/03/the-facebook-login-button-and-logging-into-your-webapp/

Comment: I honestly didn't test with your code, and FYI I'm using this line, so you may want to try if for some reason that doesn't fix it: FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', ...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response){
```

with

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response){
```

As auth.authStatusChange event trigger on status change whether already logged in or login by giving credentials.

thanks

Comment: Whenever I loads login page, it will directly redirect to my function. I want after clicking login button it should go to my function.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk See this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/
It is just event to trigger on any statuschange , its upto you that how you use it,in auth.statusChange there is status that can be connected, authorized or unknown, please see full detail on above link

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
//only works when page loads, use FB.Event.subscribe for status change      
    statusChangeCallback(response);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response){
        //yay! do whatever here, there was a status change
    },true);  

});
```