# Facebook login not responding to FB.login response

Tags: facebook

I am working on a android phonegap application with facebook integration.
FB.login(function(response) function has a response handler it is being called when
 user click on fb button, but its not getting into the function response 
or alert('test') every time. it gets into this script only when i hit
 around 5 or 6 times. wat i need is to fetch the access token the very first time i logged into facebook. i have gone through a lot of links regarding this but 
cant find an exact solution for this...

[FB login callback function not responding if user is already logged in facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541162/fb-login-callback-function-not-responding-if-user-is-already-logged-in-facebook/8743462#8743462)

Even this question seems to be same but i cant figure it out my solution.

this is the code am working :

```
<div id="data">Hello Facebooktesters, loading ...</div>

<button onclick="login()">Login</button>
<button onclick="me()">Me</button>
<button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
<button onclick="Post()">facebookWallPost</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
        try {
            alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
            FB.init({
                appId : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                nativeInterface : CDV.FB,
                useCachedDialogs : false
            });
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "FB init executed";
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }, false);

    function me() {
        FB.api('/me/friends', {
            fields : 'id, name, picture'
        }, function(response) {
            if (response.error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
            } else {
                var data = document.getElementById('data');
                fdata = response.data;
                console.log("fdata: " + fdata);
                response.data.forEach(function(item) {
                    var d = document.createElement('div');
                    d.innerHTML = "<img src="+item.picture+"/>" + item.name;
                    data.appendChild(d);
                });
            }
            var friends = response.data;
            console.log(friends.length);
            for ( var k = 0; k < friends.length && k < 200; k++) {
                var friend = friends[k];
                var index = 1;

                friendIDs[k] = friend.id;
                //friendsInfo[k] = friend;
            }
            console.log("friendId's: " + friendIDs);
        });
    }

    function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            alert('test');
            if (response.authResponse) {
                alert('logged in');
                var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
                alert(access_token);
                 window.location = "test.html"
            } else {
                alert('not logged in');
            }
        }, {
            scope : "email"
        });
    }

    function logout() {
        alert('test');
          FB.logout(function(response) {
              alert('logged out');
            //window.location.reload();
          });
    }

    function Post(ele) {
        var domain = 'http://192.168.0.46:8082/';
        console.log('Debug 1');
        var params = {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'test - test',
        link: domain+'test/test/showproddetails.action?product.productId=1',
        picture: 'http://www.careersolutions.com/test.png',
        caption: 'test',
        description: 'test'
        };
        console.log(params);
        FB.ui(params, function(obj) { console.log(obj);});
    }

</script>
```

Thank you,
raj

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolon in this line :

`window.location = "test.html"`

Comment: Nope, the semicolon is _optional_ in JavaScript in (most) cases where there is just one expression in a line of code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, some compilers will keep complaining until you fix your syntax. SOMETIMES it causes breaking of your code.The above code is working fine when ported to browser, so I thought that might be the problem :)

Thanks for bringing up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted a while ago but I would like to point out something. `FB.login` function opens a popup dialog asking if the user would like to log in to your app using Facebook. It is generally recommended that it be run after clicking a button as most browsers would block popup dialogs when a page loads. If the user had previously authorized your app then the popup dialog redirects back to your app and closes the dialog box (assuming your app is a website).

If what you intended to do was to check whether a user is logged in to your app upon page load, then it's recommended that you instead use `FB.getLoginStatus` method like so

```
function checkLoginState() {
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      // Check response.status to see if user is logged in
      alert(response.status);
   });
}
```

Refer to [this extensive documentation on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)